# Can I manually install cardano-graphql using local data?

Tags: cardano-db-sync, cardano-graphql

I'm running a relay node and have dbsync pushing data into postgresql.

To build the graphql data, do I have to use the weekly restore snapshot as described in the github page for cardano-graphql or can I cut that corner and use my local data somehow?

Does the docker instance run it's own cardano node or just the graphql API?

As a related side question - will my postgresql database be redundant when I have graphql up and running? My use case is extracting transaction metadata.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.